# Subtle difference between queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, arel

In the article *[Why Arel?](https://magicscalingsprinkles.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/why-i-wrote-arel/)*, the author poses the problem:

> Suppose we have a users table and a photos table and we want to select all user data and a *count* of the photos they have created.

His proposed solution (with a line break added) is

```
SELECT users.*, photos_aggregation.cnt
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user_id, count(*) as cnt FROM photos GROUP BY user_id)
  AS photos_aggregation
ON photos_aggregation.user_id = users.id
```

When I attempted to write such a query, I came up with

```
select users.*, if(count(photos.id) = 0, null, count(photos.id)) as cnt
from users
left join photos on photos.user_id = users.id
group by users.id
```

<sup>(The `if()` in the column list is just to get it to behave the same when a user has no photos.)</sup>

The author of the article goes on to say

> Only advanced SQL programmers know how to write this (I’ve often asked this question in job interviews I’ve never once seen anybody get it right). And it shouldn’t be hard!

I don't consider myself an "advanced SQL programmer", so I assume I'm missing something subtle. What am I missing?

Comment: Here's [some test data](https://gist.github.com/5dee7db1088287f7c5a9) if you want to play around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most DBMSs (MySQL and [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) are exceptions) the version in your question would be invalid.

You would need to write the query which does not use the derived table as

```
select users.*, CASE WHEN count(photos.id) > 0 THEN count(photos.id) END as cnt
from users
left join photos on photos.user_id = users.id
group by users.id, users.name, users.email /* and so on*/
```

MySQL allows you to select non aggregated items that are not in the `group by` list but this is only safe if they are functionally dependant on the column(s) in the `group by`.

Whilst the `group by` list is more verbose without the derived table I would expect most optimisers to be able to transform one to the other anyway. Certainly in SQL Server if it sees you are grouping by the PK and some other columns it doesn't actually do group by comparisons on those other columns.

Some discussion about this MySQL behaviour vs standard SQL is in [Debunking GROUP BY myths](http://rpbouman.blogspot.co.uk/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your version would produce an error, at least in some database engines. In MSSQL your select would generate `[Column Name] is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`. This is because you select can only contain values in the group by or the count.

You could modify your version to `select users.id, count(photo.id)` and it would work, but it would not be the same result as his query.

I would not say you have to be particularly advanced to come up with a working solution (or the specific solution he came up with) but it is necessary to do the group in a separate query  either in the join or as @ron tornambe suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the author of the article is wrong. Your solution works as well, and it may very well be faster.

Personally, I would drop the `if` alltogether. If you want to count the number of pictures, it makes sense that 'no pictures' results in `0` rather than `null`.

Comment: I agree with dropping the `if`, but I kept it to match the behavior of the original query.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can also write a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT u.*, (SELECT Count(*) FROM photos p WHERE p.userid=u.id) as cnt
FROM users u
```